# Is it possible to use an Animate.css alongside a regular CSS?

Tags: css, animate.css

I'm using a basic setup, but want to animate a

## Heading

with slideInRight when one is to scroll down. Sorry, first-time using this and it has perked my interest, I've read the installation pages and the Basic Usage pages.

Thanks!

(EDIT) Hi all, It's appeared to me that my Question was not very accurate, and that I posted this before thinking. My issue that I have now resolved,was that I was attempting to make an entire    div    section move with 'bounce'. I've, with the awesome suggestion from @ThrowingDwarf I've been able to use a class="*" and not an id="*" tag. Thanks a ton guys! I hope this helps y'all in future!

Comment: what exactly is it you wana know ?

Comment: I want to be able to use my regular CSS, for font, font size, color etc, but also animate it, so far I've only had errors with it.

Comment: better donot modify or use the same class for your CSS as the animate.css uses.. it will work superb... works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question is not really clear i am assuming you have a normal CSS file with your markup etc. And you want to have another CSS file for your animations? This is possible, you can have multiple stylesheets. However you need to be careful with names. Do not duplicate names ie. using the same class/id in both files. It can be confusing and can have undesired effects.

To load the second CSS just do it the same way you load up the normal CSS. 
Note: elements can have only one ID value but they can have multiple classes.